# How to create a meta-playlist?

Tags: itunes

I'd like to create a meta-playlist that plays various playlists I created in order, with the added functionality to set limits on how many songs will play from each playlist.  Can this be done, either in iTunes or other software?

My example is the following:

I grew up listening to The Beatles albums and I'm accustomed to hearing their songs in a specific order.  For example, the album "Revolver" has 14 songs and it starts with Taxman, followed by Eleanor Rigby, followed by I'm Only Sleeping, etc.

Over the years, I've collected cover versions of Beatles songs.  Let's say I now have five cover versions of each song on Revolver.

I'd like to hear new versions of Revolver: that is, to hear a randomly selected cover version of the song Taxman, followed by a cover of Eleanor Rigby, followed by I'm Only Sleeping, etc.

Doable?

Answer (score 1):

You could do a whole gas factory for that in AppleScript.

You could also achieve that with folders and playlists .m3u.

Let’s say :

- One folder = one album. Inside the folder, 14 .m3u files.
- One .m3u file = one playlist = one title of the album = 5 versions of the song.

And you could play the folder with VLC. However, this would not be prettily integrated in iTunes.